# how to disable one input field if another is filled in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am unable to find a solution. please help me.
I want to disable 2nd input field if the 1st input field is filled. in the same way, if we input the 2nd input field then the 1st input field should be disabled.
like this image
[image]

we need to enter only reduce or increase the price.

Comment: Please ´post the options you have tried and any errors related.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: `$("#input2").prop('disabled', $("#input1").val() !="");`

Comment: You can match the .eq() if each column has different classnames